# Comparing Two SP's Performance SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

there is any simple way to know which one of two SQL Store procedure works better?

Comment: Define 'works better'.

Comment: If you are wanting to compare performance then compare the actual Execution Plan s for both stored procs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649109/what-tools-are-out-there-for-profiling-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-other-tha

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the *Include Actual Execution Plan* before running both sp (on the same run) and check the percentages